# How to compare an array with the last inserted array in a csv file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I generate arrays that I append to a file with:

```
require 'csv`
CSV.open(FILE_NAME, "a+") do |csv|
  csv << array
end
```

I want to skip the insertion if the index `[0]` value is identical to the last inserted array's `[0]`.

How can I read the last line/row of a csv file and compare it's values with an array that's still not inserted?

Comment: I do not see an elegant way of doing this efficiently. Either you will have to read the whole CSV-file on every append which is horribly inefficient (O(n**2) in the number of lines) or you would have to extend the `CSV` class to remember the last line that was added to it, but that would require to change the semantics of your code quite considerably. Anyway, you should clarify where you want your `array` to come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working around some of what @Patru said:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.open(FILE_NAME, "a+")
first_row = csv.first
csv.rewind
last_row = csv.reverse_each.first


csv << ary unless ary == first_row or ary == last_row
```

Comment: That looks much better than I thought it would become. I did not know about `#reverse_each` and did not care to look it up. Thumbs up on this one and if you throw in some `unless array[0] == last_row[0]` you might actually solve @Numbers problem completely.